# Laravel Scout does not respect Algolia's order

Tags: laravel, algolia, laravel-scout

I try to use Laravel Scout with Algolia as my search engine.

I use it like this

```
MyModel::search('my query')->paginate()->pluck('id');
```

Problem is, Algolia returns the correct order let's say some records with ids `3, 1, 2` but when Laravel fetches the records on the database, the ids are like `1, 2, 3` (ordered by id).

Am I using Scout wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding the issue [#341](https://github.com/laravel/scout/issues/341) on the scout repository, it seems to be a scout problem being investigated.

### EDIT

The issue is now fixed as of PR [#369](https://github.com/laravel/scout/pull/369) ( version > 7.0)

Answer (score -2):

You have to edit vendor file in your laravel project:

```
vendor/laravel/scout/src/Searchable.php
```

and edit return statement of **getScoutModelsByIds()** function into:

```
    $ids_ordered = implode(',', $ids);

    return $query->whereIn(
        $this->getScoutKeyName(), $ids
    )->orderByRaw(DB::raw("FIELD(id, $ids_ordered)"))->get();
```

Comment: Hi and thanks for the reply. I think it’s very wrong to suggest an edit in the vendor directory. Please rewrite your answer or delete it to not confuse beginners. Thanks again